# Windows 10 missing service

Tags: windows-10, services, windows-services, smartcard

I'm trying to use a smart card on my computer and I can't get it to read on one of my computers even though using the exact same reader works on the other. Both are running Windows 10 21H1. Plugging in the card reader into the non-working computer does install a device in Device Manager so the computer can detect the reader.

One thing I noticed that's different is that the working computer has a Smart Card service but the non-working does not have this service. My guess is I need that service to get it to recognize. But this is where I'm lost. So far, I've tried running the following:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
sfc /scannow
```

It did fix some things, but the Smart Card service still isn't showing up after a reboot.

Any pointers are much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the service? You should edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound It says in my description that it's the Smart Card service. Is there an edit you'd suggest that makes that more obvious?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the card reader from device manager being sure to check the box that says to remove drivers? Have you tried sfc /scannow ? Maybe the service is truly broken & no repairs target it to fix. Besides resetting or reinstalling windows my only other thought is to manually create service hopefully with command sc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know the model of your card-reader.
You could look for a driver on the website of its manufacturer.

Use the `regsvr32` command to re-register the following dll files
(whichever ones exist on your computer).
For example: `regsvr32 scarddlg.dll`.

```
scarddlg.dll   SCardDlg - Smart Card Common Dialog
scardssp.dll   Smart Card Base Service Providers
sccbase.dll    Infineon SICRYPT Base Smart Card CSP
sccsccp.dll    Infineon SICRYPT Smart Card Crypto Provider COM Objects
scredir.dll    Smart Card Redirection for TS
slbcsp.dll     Schlumberger Smart Card CryptoAPI Library
slbiop.dll     Schlumberger Smart Card Interoperability Library v2
slbrccsp.dll   Schlumberger Smart Card CryptoAPI Resource File
```

If the above steps do not help with the issue, try a
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This is the same as doing a major upgrade of Windows,
so take the appropriate backups.

Comment: I ended up needing to do the reinstall and that fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

On both systems, in search box on task bar, type "services" and start it.
Look for: "Smart Card" "Manages access to smart cards read by this ..."

If no smart card reader is attached its "Status" should be blank and "Startup Type" should be "Automatic(Trigger Start)"
Close services and inset a reader.
Bring up Services again:
with reader inserted, the "Status" should be "Running".

You can also use Task Manager to see the Services with Name of "SCardSrv", PID, Description "Smart Card" and Status of "Running"

You did not say what reader you are using or if other readers have been used on the failing machine. When a new driver is installed, it should have turned on Automatic(Trigger Startup).

Right click on entry and then Properties and you can set "Automatic".

Comment: My issue is that The smart card service isn't in the services list to start. I'm trying to figure out how to get it to show up

Comment: To answer your other statement, I haven't tried other readers. But as I said, the device manager correctly shows the reader once I plug it in